# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 when setting array's index value

Tags: java

I'm trying to set an index in an array of bytes to 1, and when I do it, it gives me the error "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0" for line 2.

```
byte[] b = {};
b[0] = 1;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You had declared arraylength to 0 watch it out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've initialised an array of length 0.  'b[0]' references the *first* element of this, which doesn't exist (it has length 0).

```
byte[] b = new byte[1];
b[0] = 1;
```

or

```
byte[] b = {1};
```

is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Your array has size 0 so it cannot contain any values ergo you cannot set any values.
You have to create your array with a size > 0.

```
byte[] b = new byte[1]
b[0] = 1;
```

or alternatively

```
byte[] b = {42};
b[0] = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are saying 
`byte[] b = {};`, you are making an array that holds no elements at all.  So calling it's first index will return that error.

Instead, do this:

```
byte[] b = new byte[10];
b[0] = 1;
```

The first line you are declaring and setting the length, and the second line you are setting the first element to 1.

Answer (score 0):

I think you not initialized array. 
you are saying `byte[] b = {};` I think equivalent `byte[] b = new byte[0];`
So, if you put any values to array, then program will return that error.